# PEP8 Ошибка E712 при отборе через .loc в DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

```
df.loc[df.biz_id == True, 'biz_id_zak'] = 'b2b'
df.loc[df.biz_id == False, 'biz_id_zak'] = 'b2c'
```

Условие работает - данные отбираются. Загвоздка в том, что данная выборка противоречит рекомендациям PEP:

**Comparison to true should be 'if cond is true:' or 'if cond:' (E712)**

Пытался переписать внутри этой строчки:

```
df.loc[df.biz_id is True, 'biz_id_zak'] = 'b2b'
```

**KeyError: 'cannot use a single bool to index into setitem'**

А если так:

```
df.loc[df.biz_id == True, 'biz_id_zak'] = 'b2b'
```

**SyntaxError: invalid syntax**

Пытаюсь работать над своим 'плохо'-кодом, стараясь исправлять всё, что хоть как-то не нравится редактору. Помогите пожалуйста оптимальным однострочным условием, чтобы совместно с .loc работало.

Comment: а в чем вы пишите и какой линтер используете?

Comment: Редактор Spyder/ Линтер встроенный

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Это ложное срабатывание линтера, а потому его лучше заглушить:

```
df.loc[df.biz_id == True, 'biz_id_zak'] = 'b2b'  # noqa: E712
```